# Can .net applications work on liferay?

Tags: .net, liferay, portlet, portal

I wanted to know whether applications developed in .net framework are deployable as portlets in the Liferay portal. Or is it restricted to java applications alone.

Comment: Your question has been answered already here: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/5701187

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a company offering WSRP interface for .NET, but for some reason it completely disappeared from the earth. WSRP is "Web Services for Remote Portlets" and allowed .NET applications to be hosted on a separate server but still being consumed on a Java portal server.

Without such tricks (and the ones that Parkash mentions) Java and .NET are almost mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0):

Web technology hss evolved enormously. Nowadays, integration of third party application has become quite handy through Iframe and web-services.

There are certain approaches you can adopt, depending on your requirement and depth of your integration:

**1. IFrame Portlet:** If your .Net application is running on separate server, you can render it through Liferay's Iframe portlet.

**2. Web Service:** If you want your remote application logic to be more native, you can create a portlet and consume webserives created by your .Net application.

**3. Single Sign On (SSO):** You can integrate your both application through some SSO setup to share data.